# how to locate 'imqi.hpp' from node-gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, ibm-mq, node-gyp

I am trying to use "nan" module to call MQ_CONNECT() from node.js

See

[Node.js and C/C++ integration: how to properly implement callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862736/node-js-and-c-c-integration-how-to-properly-implement-callbacks)
and
https://github.com/nodejs/nan

When I use "node-gyp" it says it can not find "imqi.hpp", the MQ header

As far as I can see, the path to MQ includes has to be provided in "binding.gyp", and I have tried this without success:

```
{
    "targets": [
            {
                    "target_name": "mqconn",
                    "sources": [
                            "initall.cc",
                            "mqconn.cc"
                    ],
                    "include_dirs": [
                            "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
                            "c:\MQ\tools\cplus\include"
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Does anyboby have a clue on how to fix this ?
Sebastian.

PD.- of course, the file is where the path indicates:

```
c:\>dir c:\MQ\tools\cplus\include\imqi.hpp
Volume in drive C is OS
Volume Serial Number is 12AA-0601

Directory of c:\MQ\tools\cplus\include

27/06/2013  02:00             1.538 imqi.hpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because binding.gyp is in JSON, the String `"c:\MQ\tools\cplus\include"`is a standard JavaScript String, and therefore the `\` needs to be escaped to `\\`.

So you should replace `"c:\MQ\tools\cplus\include"` into `"c:\\MQ\\tools\\cplus\\include"`.

I hope that fixes the problem...